# db:migrate for a Models gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, migration

So we abstracted our models into a gem because multiple applications use the same model set. The trouble is performing creating and performing migrations. Because it is a gem we basically  removed rails.

It can't perform rails g or rake.

If we try to keep the config and script folder which allows that, the other applications will complain when they use the models gem.

We're hacking around this by allowing one specific application to perform all migrations.

Perhaps the better question is: What is the best way to modularize common models such that you retain rails g and rake db:migrate?

I probably explained this poorly, please ask any questions.

Thanks,
Justin

Comment: Hi, how did you end up modularizing the common models?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using version control? You could look into just using a git submodule for the models folder which would allow you to use rails generators on all applications and keep them all in sync. Basically a submodule is a git repository inside an existing repository.

The commands are simple as well, to get started look into [this guide here](http://help.github.com/submodules/) overall it should help you reduce the complexity of your application.